# Print ListBox Control Contents

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a listbox control (in a WinForms application) that lists a bunch of statistics about records selected from a database.

Is there an easy way using VB .NET to take the contents of this listbox and send it all to the printer, or at least have one of those standard windows print dialogs come up, prompting the user for which printer to send the listbox contents to?  Doesn't have to be fancy or anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776452/how-to-print-in-vb-net/5780300#5780300

The first answer has a solution for printing a panel in Winforms that should be applicable to your situation.

EDIT WITH UPDATE:

Take a look at this MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print.aspx

If you can't use the method shown in the other question, you can always handle the PrintPage event of the PrintDocument object.  Particularly look at the pd_PrintPage sub in that example, as it is the sub that handles the PrintPage event.  You should be able to modify that sub to use the contents of your ListBox.  You will iterate through your ListBox and "draw" each string onto the ev.Graphics object.  The only tricky part is deciding how much will fit on one page, but the example covers that also.

Comment: That seems close, but my listbox's contents actually scroll down below the visible portion on screen.  I guess I am wondering if I should just write the contents out to a text file, and then print that text file maybe?

Comment: @Joebocop, edited my answer with some more relevant information.